# how can we divide screen in two equal width in android programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, size, pixel

i was developing android application but based on the screen sizes element size getting changed.is there is any solutions to divide the screen sizes equally.i am getting different sizes in different screens like 5inches and  3.7 inches

[image]
[image]

My Code is...

```
lView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
 lView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 220);
 GradientDrawable gdtitle = new GradientDrawable();

 gdtitle.setCornerRadius(5);
 ImageView title = new ImageView(Main2Activity.this);
 title.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
 title.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
 title.setBackgroundDrawable(gdtitle);
 lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
 lView.addView(title);


 GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
 gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); // Changes this drawbale to use a single color instead of a gradient
 gd.setCornerRadius(5);
 gd.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000);

  int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
  int Height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
  TextView uname1 = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
  uname1.setText("Hello , " + Sessionname);
  uname1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  uname1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#003366"));
  uname1.setTextSize(20);
  uname1.setWidth(width);
  uname1.setLayoutParams(l2);

  et1 = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
  et1.setHeight(Height);
  et1.setWidth(width);
  et1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  et1.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  et1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  et1.setHint("Select Date");
  et1.setBackgroundDrawable(gd3);
  et1.setTextSize(15);
  et1.setLayoutParams(l2);

  LinearLayout.LayoutParams l4 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  l4.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
  lHorizontalView1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
  lHorizontalView1.setLayoutParams(l4);
  lHorizontalView1.addView(uname1);
  lHorizontalView1.addView(et1);
  lView.addView(lHorizontalView1);



  GradientDrawable gd4 = new GradientDrawable();
  gd4.setCornerRadius(30);
  gd4.setColor(Color.parseColor("#5CB85C"));
  gd4.setStroke(3, 0xFFFFFFFF);

  Intime = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
  Intime.setHint("In Time");
  Intime.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  Intime.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  Intime.setTextSize(15);
  Intime.setHeight(Height);
  Intime.setWidth(width);
  Intime.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  Intime.setLayoutParams(l2);
  Intime.setBackgroundDrawable(gd4);
  lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

   Outtime = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
   Outtime.setHint("Out Time");
   Outtime.setTextSize(15);
   Outtime.setHeight(Height);
   Outtime.setWidth(width);
   Outtime.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
   Outtime.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
   Outtime.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
   Outtime.setLayoutParams(l2);
   Outtime.setBackgroundDrawable(gd4);
   lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

   LinearLayout lHorizontalView = new LinearLayout(Main2Activity.this);
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams l3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   l3.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;


   lHorizontalView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
   lHorizontalView.setLayoutParams(l3);
   lHorizontalView.addView(Intime);
   lHorizontalView.addView(Outtime);
   lView.addView(lHorizontalView);
```

Comment: Have you tried with weight

Answer (score 3):

You should use **[DisplayMetrics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)**

```
 DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

**Example**

```
 RelativeLayout rl_firstObj=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl_first);
 rl_firstObj.getLayoutParams().width=DeviceTotalWidth*50/100;

 RelativeLayout rl_secondObj=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl_second);
 rl_secondObj.getLayoutParams().width=DeviceTotalWidth*50/100;
```

Answer (score 0):

For buttons parent view use linearlayout and set

`param.weight = 1`

for each button.

Answer (score 0):

Using LinearLayouts and assigning weights to the views inside it will divide the seperate the views with the same ratio no matter the screen size. Here, I've assigned weight 1 to both the views, thus they will be shown side my side divided equally on the screen.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);

        textView1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);

        textView2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
```

I have taken a linear layout with parameter weight as 1 and divide that in two views.Here i used textviews u can take any view in your code.Please let me know if face any issue

Answer (score 0):

if any one has issue in dividing layout into to same size sections or any other scale I used to do this via display metrics but the down side of this approach is that it is happening in the runtime and you must wait for the application to measure the screen width and height.
in my opinion a better way is to use constraint layout
below you can see a sample where I divided the screen into two sections as you can see  it's working both on portrait and landscape modes:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".views.main.fragment.HomeMainFragment"
    tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">




    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_half_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline_half_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/barChart_site_state"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline_half_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/imageSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:sliderAnimationDuration="600"
        app:sliderAutoCycleDirection="back_and_forth"
        app:sliderAutoCycleEnabled="true"
        app:sliderIndicatorAnimationDuration="600"
        app:sliderIndicatorGravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        app:sliderIndicatorMargin="15dp"
        app:sliderIndicatorOrientation="horizontal"
        app:sliderIndicatorPadding="3dp"
        app:sliderIndicatorRadius="2dp"
        app:sliderIndicatorSelectedColor="#5A5A5A"
        app:sliderIndicatorUnselectedColor="#FFF"
        app:sliderScrollTimeInSec="1"
        app:sliderStartAutoCycle="true" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: landscape]

[image: portrait]